# Keycloak - get access token with Postman - access type bearer-only

Tags: keycloak

I hope you're doing well :) I am new to Keycloak, I've took a project done last year by an trainee and I want to get the token via Postman and it is not working I have: *invalid_client, bearer-only not allowed* as you can see in the picture : [image]

Setting for realm faq are the following : [image]

And for the client( test_client) I have : [image][image] . The project dates from the last year and it was working, and now I didn't change anything in the configuration I am not able to get the token. Do you have an idea? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to get access token for a particular user account within a realm, then we can do so via

[image: Postman snapshot showing the api call and the response]

Hope this helps with your doubt. I'm also trying to learn how to work with keycloak.

Comment: Hey, so cool thank you, yes indeed I want to get the token for the test_client account and in the setting client settings I have a bearer-only access type as you cas see in the last picture, I just took this project from a trainee during his internship, in your configuration you put a public/confidential access? do you know with bearer-only what is wrong in this configuration?

Comment: yes, I'm using public access type. With bearer-only, it seems we can only validate a particular token. " 'Confidential' clients require a secret to initiate login protocol. 'Public' clients do not require a secret. 'Bearer-only' clients are web services that never initiate a login." - this is the description given by keycloak